# Vega JS specification fails to resolve fieldValue

Tags: vega

I have a Vega specification with data containing values nested in an object that I'd like to map to fill color. E.g, here is one datum from a hypothetical data array:

```
{"category": "A", "amount": 3, "color":{"a":1, "b":2} }
```

I would like to pass the value of `datum.color.a` to a scale to generate fill color. To that end, given a signal value `color_scheme` set to `"color.a"` and a simple ordinal scale `color` I expected to be able to do the following on my mark definition:

```
"fill": {"field": {"signal":"color_scheme"}, "scale":"color"}
```

But, it doesn't work. Why not?

Here is a live example: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aACwAGNTPg0yWNACYNMnEgUKa4smgEyFSTClQBtUOKQI4aEA6YAbTzLESL4McBBoLiBQ9uRsAE4Anl4AgtIg7mwM4phoAMwyUGy+8WigjgCMMkwGAL41UqDRmLGJXgBCaRlZOag2UUUlqGUGVWjldQC6NRMyEDpuvuHOru6e6IXFcQD6XIgBIEEha-2blCjTs9H+S5FuHl4bJTKYCTjH8eYLaQpsyBYRlX0MxAcSQljWThAflCaQScF8xVkICmDRAd2OAA9oMF9i83l4mGCFN9fkh-kMQHYHF4fP40gAzGjw4nrGJkeJJeogsFkY7yJQwNImMwWKyoNSUNR9OKZcQszBxUL1Fb3dAJbF02yk8mgKmObxIPz7RnMrxdbIgLniGhQNYK0IyUHgrzaXQ5C4gZBxADWN1AeOOcTgUByMnpMoQpUp9n1tM8XLg4kKCjWoETzTiUYxUY1mNzDKZvhZUTZHMtMn5ygp+fQWKu+0JcrGXKS1frXnV7bDheL5vdMgS+hz7bV+cCwRh4rqMgYOCpqZAjIRUZNRZz82CDwG2129y5NZOJTqkxqQA

Comment: Just encountered the same thing, this is weird behavior.

Comment: Link to the [vega issue](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/3054) created by OP.